# Catch Exception A Throw Exception B - Coverage Junit5

Tags: junit5

Iam catch FeignException, but im throws FeingClientException(customized exception).

Sonar says that this FeingClientExceptionis not coveraged by junit test.

Any idea to cover it.

[image]

My exception is like this:

```java
public class FeignClientException extends RuntimeException {

    public FeignClientException(FeignException ex, ErrorMessageEnum errorMessageEnum, ContextExceptionEnum contextExceptionEnum, String cpf) {
        throwException(ex, contextExceptionEnum, errorMessageEnum, cpf);
    }

    private void throwException(FeignException ex, ContextExceptionEnum contextExceptionEnum, ErrorMessageEnum errorMessageEnum, String cpf) {
        if (ex.status() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value() || ex instanceof FeignException.NotFound) {
            throw new FeignClientNotFoundException(
                    errorMessageEnum != null ? errorMessageEnum.msgUserFormatted(cpf) : ErrorMessageEnum.REGISTRO_NAO_ENCONTRADO.msgUserFormatted(cpf),
                    errorMessageEnum != null ? errorMessageEnum.msgDeveloper() : ErrorMessageEnum.REGISTRO_NAO_ENCONTRADO.msgDeveloper(),
                    String.valueOf(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()),
                    contextExceptionEnum.value());
        }
        if (ex.status() == HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value() || ex instanceof RetryableException) {
            throw new ServicoForaDoArException(
                    ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_FORA_AR.msgUserFormatted(contextExceptionEnum.value()),
                    ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_FORA_AR.msgDeveloper(),
                    String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value()),
                    contextExceptionEnum.value());
        }
        if (ex.status() == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
            throw new FeignClientInternalServerErrorException(
                    ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_RETORNOU_ERRO.msgUserFormatted(contextExceptionEnum.value()),
                    ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_RETORNOU_ERRO.msgDeveloper(),
                    String.valueOf(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()),
                    contextExceptionEnum.value());
        }
        throw new FeignBadGatewayException (
                ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_RETORNOU_ERRO.msgUserFormatted(contextExceptionEnum.value()),
                ErrorMessageEnum.SERVICO_RETORNOU_ERRO.msgDeveloper(),
                String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY.value()),
                contextExceptionEnum.value());
    }
}
```

My test is:

```java
    void test2() {
        doThrow(FeignException.NotFound.class).when(preAprovadoClient).consultaPreAprovadoCDC(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
        assertThrows(FeignClientException.FeignClientNotFoundException.class, () ->{
            PreAprovado preAprovado = preAprovadoGateway.consultarPreAprovadoCDC("01234567890");
        });
    }
```

Comment: So what does your current test look like?

Comment: Can you share what was mocked in this tests

Comment: @GeorgeLvov FeignException is into spring library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mocking the wrong method. You're calling the method `consultarPreAprovadoCDC` with one parameter, but you have mocked it with two `String` parameters, maybe that is causing this confusion.

Try to either changing the call to use two `String` parameters or mock the method with only one `anyString()` as parameter.